# Problems with COMBINING OVERLINE unicode rendering in Emacs 27.1

Tags: unicode

[Emacs 27.1 from manjaro arch]

Hi,
can anyone help me with the following?  I'd like to render "x bar" (x with a horizontal bar) above it in unicode.  I can get in Emacs 27.1, using monaco (check1), but not in other fonts, like Roboto mono.  See screenshot below.  On the left is the test file, unicode1.el, (availabe from
http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk//user/sje30/unicode1.el ) in gedit where the xbar renders okay in Roboto Mono. On the right is the output when (check2) has been run; the  information in the *Help* buffer shows that x has not been combined.

[image: roboto]

If you run (check1) you get the desired output:

[image]